# SQL Max() for corresponding none null values

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table and I need to return the highest colC number where colA is not null. This this case that would be |No | ID1234 | 10. Text.|

Originally I was using strtok(colC,'.',1)*1 to extract the number from colC but now I am stuck on how I can return the MAX. Any help is much appreciated.

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | ID1234 | 1. text |
| No | ID1234 | 2. text |
|  | ID1234 | 3. text |
| No | ID1234 | 4. text |
| Yes | ID1234 | 5. text |
| Yes | ID1234 | 6. text |
|  | ID1234 | 7. text |
|  | ID1234 | 8. text |
|  | ID1234 | 9. text |
| No | ID1234 | 10. text |
|  | ID1234 | 11. text |
|  | ID1234 | 12. text |

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is the issue parsing the string in `colC`?

Comment: If colc is a text column, then the highest value is '9. text', because '9' comes later than the leading '1' of '10. text' in an ordered list. So maybe you have an issue with how you are storing your data. If you want 10 > 9, then store that number separate from the text.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.  This shouldn't be overly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

why not this?

```
select max(colC)
from table
where colA is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qualify` -- assuming that `colC` is indeed orderable using strings:

```
select t.*
from t
where colA is not null
qualify row_number() over (order by colC desc) = 1;
```

It is not clear, though, if the issue is just ordering `colC` or if it is parsing `colC` for the initial number.  If the latter, you might want something like this:

```
qualify row_number() over (order by length(regexp_substr(colC, '^[^ ]+')) desc, colC desc) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you this get me in the right direction and I am able to get the result for the table with a single ID. However, I need to run this on a table that has multiple IDs. So I would want the Max of cast(strtok(colC,'.',1) as int) for each ID where colA is not null.

Comment: @user2865268 . . . Just add `partition by id` to the window frame specification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this for parsing ColC to get the numeric portion:

```
cast(strtok(colc,'.',1) as integer) as der_col
```

You can use qualify on that derived column:

```
    select
    ...
 cast(strtok(colc,'.',1) as integer) as der_col,
...
    from
    yourtable
    ...
    qualify row_number() over (order by der_col ASC) = 1
```